# Google Spreadsheets: how to display the amount of cells that contain specific multiple text and numbers

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet in Google Spreadsheets to use for score keeping in a pool league and have run into a problem.

I have two sheets in the spreadsheet.  The first is called "Actual Scoresheet" and contains scores from the game.  The second sheet is called "Player Stats" and contains stats from each player during the game.

In the "Actual Scoresheet", I have a range of cells (for example `F37:T37`) where the scores from each game are entered.  There are 4 different possibilities for a win that can be entered in any of the cells in this range.  These possibilities are "14", "BR", "TR", "WZ".

In the "Player Stats", I have a cell that I want to show the total amount of wins in the range of cells contained in "Actual Scoresheet".

I tried this formula

```
=COUNTIFS('Actual Scoresheet'!F37:T37, "14", 'Actual Scoresheet'!F37:T37, "BR", 'Actual Scoresheet'!F37:T37, "WZ", 'Actual Scoresheet'!F37:T37, "TR")
```

but it is only returning a value of 0 even though cells `F37:T37` contain 2 `TR`'s and 2 `14`'s, which should return a value of 4.

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks

Comment: At least in Excel, `COUNTIFS()` requires that *all* of the criteria have to match *for any given "row"* to count that row. You maybe want a sum of `COUNTIF()`'s instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per +Tim Williams' comment, you essentially have an OR condition rather than an AND; so you can sum individual `COUNTIF()`s, or a bit shorter:

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(COUNTIF('Actual Scoresheet'!F37:T37,{"14";"BR";"TR";"WZ"})))`

Comment: In this specific case I don't think you need `Arrayformula` - should work with just `=SUM(COUNTIF('Actual Scoresheet'!F37:T37,{"14";"BR";"TR";"WZ"}))` - the same formula works in excel, again without "array entry"

Comment: In Excel that is true; in Google Sheets, you definitely need an array calculation enabler (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r4-u43m2EIPzuHhMVNBzIzIGgENDi-FMVCohjimcVhw/edit?usp=sharing). While there is an Excel tag here, the title and wording of the post suggests this is a question about Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Given tag, Excel version:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF('Actual Scoresheet'!F37:T37,{14,"BR","TR","WZ"}))
```

or for a locale with`;` as the separator:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF('Actual Scoresheet'!F37:T37;{14;"BR";"TR";"WZ"}))
```

<strike>Again both are to be entered as an array formula, in Excel with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.</strike>

CSE entry **not** necessary, see the maestro's comment below.

`14` may be either a number or a string.

Comment: No need for "array entry" here. Typically if you list the criteria in an "array constant as per `{14,"BR","TR","WZ"}` array entry won't be required - although if you use a range like Z1:Z4 for the criteria then you **do** need array entry (or you can use SUMPRODUCT in place of SUM to avoid)

Comment: OP clearly uses a Google Spreadsheet. You should therefore migrate to Web Applications.

Comment: I don't see how that is normal. One is a web app, the other one isn't. Even with the new Google Spreadsheets, the two are very different !!

Comment: Well, shall we review them together and determine if they can be migrated to Web Apps?

Comment: Why don't you join me here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13056/spreadsheet-nerds